# CPI from Program A to B via a Rust crate?

Tags: solana-program, rust, cpi

so what i want to do is I want to do a CPI call From program B to program A, But I want to this via a rust crate, not from program B. Like this

```
use Crate::create_cpi;


fn do_something(ctx ...) -> Result<()>{

   create_cpi( data)?;
}
```

here Crate is a rust crate, i want to do the CPI from the rust Crate (If Possible), Or it should return something like CPI Context or Instruction, so The user can just sign that instruction and send that transaction without much hassle. i want the user to pass as less data as possible. so they can write their code more without worrying about the CPI.

does anyone have any idea how to pull it off or any example they know of? Any reference will be helpful
Thanks!

Comment: If your question in answered. Please mark this as answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to create the 2 programs. Let's define 2 programs, `puppet` and `puppet-master` where `puppet-master` does a CPI into `puppet`.

```
anchor init puppet
anchor new puppet-master
```

Then you need to import the `puppet` program into the `puppet-master` program by adding the following line to the `[dependencies]` section of the `Cargo.toml` file inside the `puppet-master` program folder:

```
puppet = { path = "../puppet", features = ["cpi"]}
```

> The features = ["cpi"] is used so we can not only use puppet's types
> but also its instruction builders and cpi functions. Without those, we
> would have to use low level solana syscalls. Fortunately, anchor
> provides abstractions on top of those. By enabling the cpi feature,
> the puppet-master program gets access to the puppet::cpi module.
> Anchor generates this module automatically and it contains tailor-made
> instructions builders and cpi helpers for the program.

Answer (score -3):

Import the program b in program a cargo.toml like it is done in pic
[image: refer this]